# chromedriver error "stale element not found" returned with findElements call

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am getting a stacktrace returned by chromedriver:

```
{"value":{"error":"stale element reference","message":"stale element reference: stale element not found
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.150)","stacktrace":"0   chromedriver                        0x000000010da1e909 chromedriver + 2533641
1   chromedriver                        0x000000010e0a8d53 chromedriver + 9391443
2   chromedriver                        0x000000010d7dc3c3 chromedriver + 164803
3   chromedriver                        0x000000010d7df181 chromedriver + 176513
4   chromedriver                        0x000000010d7deff6 chromedriver + 176118
...
```

I have instantiated chromedriver, and used curl to isolate the problem with this statement:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:49308/session/35095613f12e3174d898fde5e08690e4/elements -d '{"using":"css selector","value":"body"}'
```

This looks for the *body* DOM object, which should always exist.

I have run this from a different project within my monorepo and it works, as well as running Firefox as a client while chrome is inspecting and it works as well.

So it must be something to do with how I instantiate chromedriver, but I do not see any difference between the other project.

Does anyone have any idea whats going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand. please explain?

Comment: please add the code , just add waits and see if that works

Comment: use time.sleep() first before using explicit wait to check whether wait really helps

Comment: Sorry, I am using inspection mode `--inspect-brk` with breaks at different parts f the code.  Other commands like newSession, getStatus, executeScript, get all work.  Even executing a script that gets the object by classname and clicks it, like this:
```
driver.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName(\"" + chartName + "\")[0].click()");
```
works.  It seems like the server is not creating the metadata required to allow the client retrieve/find and return objects, like some things I have read in the W3C mode.  But I have also tried to turn W3C off.  using latest v of chrome 88

Comment: I also added a 5 second sleep() before the driver.findElements() but same response with or without debugging

Comment: OK, i am starting to isolate it more.  Seems like there are some scripts that run and generate the DOM, when I take them out, and put in a dummy static DOM, it seems to work.  Its clear that the scripts run before I query the server for the objects, but I am trying to figure out why any scripts would impact the results (or making objects stale when searching?). If anyone knows, please don't hesitate. thanks!